# Animated GIFs are only transparent on their first frame (Python PIL)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, transparency, animated-gif

The following code creates a GIF from two images:

```
# GIFs are always palette images so they would be converted later anyway
im1 = PIL.Image.open('grin-emoji-by-twitter-rgba.png').convert('P')
im2 = PIL.Image.open('grin-emoji-by-twitter-rgba-2.png').convert('P')

im1.save('output.gif', save_all=True, append_images=[im2, im1, im2], loop=0, duration=200, transparency=255)
```

However the result is unexpectedly wrong. The first frame is fine, but subsequent frames contain a black rectangle around the updating region instead of transparency:

[image]

In my opinion the error is as follows: On the first image we specify the index 255 to be the index for completely transparent color. However the `save` function only seems to convert index 255 to transparency on the first frame, but skips this step on all other frames.

Is there any way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to my other answer, you can also just **[set the `disposal` value to 2](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#saving)**:

```
im1.save('output.gif', save_all=True, append_images=[im2, im1, im2], 
         loop=0, duration=200, transparency=255, disposal=2)
```

Note that unlike my other answer this does not work 100% of the time, as the transparency channel can jump around to other indexes. :-/ This only seems to happen in longer GIFs with many colors in them however.

Left: This answer, Right: Other answer with manual alignment

[image: example of bug persisting]  [image: example of bug fixed]

Edit: [Here](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1976#issuecomment-800854435) it's claimed this got **fixed** in newer versions of pillow! (I think 8.1.2+)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way. **We can manually edit the color palette to move transparency from index 255 to 0.** `save` will not misbehave if transparency is at index 0 instead of 255.

I accomplished this by right-shifting the whole color-palette by one index, so index 5 becomes index 6, index 255 becomes index 0, and so on.

In the worst case (e.g. long colorful GIF) the transparency is NOT always at index 255 and we have to manually align it to index 0 (see `shiftme` line).

```
im1 = PIL.Image.open('grin-emoji-by-twitter-rgba.png').convert('P')
im2 = PIL.Image.open('grin-emoji-by-twitter-rgba-2.png').convert('P')

p1 = im1.getpalette()
p2 = im2.getpalette()

# if you know a data point in the resulting image that will be
# transparent you can also set it directly e.g. 'shiftme = -frame[0][0]'
shiftme = 1       
im1 = (numpy.array(im1) + shiftme) % 256  # shift data pointing into palette
im2 = (numpy.array(im2) + shiftme) % 256

im1 = PIL.Image.fromarray( im1 ).convert('P')
im2 = PIL.Image.fromarray( im2 ).convert('P')

im1.putpalette( p1[-3*shiftme:] + p1[:-3*shiftme] )  # shift palette
im2.putpalette( p2[-3*shiftme:] + p2[:-3*shiftme] )  # NB this is NOT '-4' as it is RGB not RGBA

print(numpy.array(im1))
print(numpy.array(im2))

im1.save('output.gif', save_all=True, append_images=[im2, im1, im2], loop=0, duration=200, transparency=0)
```

**Result**

[image]