# How to convert PNG images to a transparent GIF?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, png, transparency, gif

I'm trying to convert a list of PNG images with a transparent background to a GIF, while keeping the background transparency. I took this bit of code I found, and adapted it:

```py
import os
from PIL import Image

# Create the frames
frames = []

path = "directory/to/my/png/images"
for frame in os.listdir(path):
    new_frame = Image.open(path + "/" + frame)
    frames.append(new_frame)

# Save into a GIF file
frames[0].save(path + "/../output/animation.gif", format='GIF',
               append_images=frames[1:],
               save_all=True,
               duration=41, loop=1, transparency=0)
```

It is opening all the PNG images I have in a folder, and export them to a GIF, but the background is black. I have looked at the [PIL documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#png), but I don't seem to understand how the `transparency` parameter works, or I think I am using it wrong.

Comment: try transparency=100 ?

Comment: I tried with 0, 100 and 255 and none of them seem to change something

Comment: or try new_frame = Image.open(path + "/" + frame, mode='RGBA') or frames[0].save(path + "/../output/animation.gif", format='GIF',
               append_images=frames[1:],
               save_all=True,
               duration=41, loop=1, transparency=0, mode='RGBA')

Comment: I am not sure how the images are read by default by PIL , try to find that and be sure that by default they are saved with alpha channel (the one that gives transpareny)

Comment: mode in open() correspond only to read/write not RGBA. I tried mode='RGBA' in the save but doesn't work neither

Comment: for i in frames: print(i.mode)

Comment: Image.open(filename, 'RGBA') ?? without mode ?

Comment: ValueError: bad mode 'RGBA'
Anyway, all my frames are already in RGBA (  print(i.mode) returns "RGBA")

Comment: ok I think I dont I know how a layered gif works

Comment: check about the disposal value : https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#saving

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59729587/animated-gifs-are-only-transparent-on-their-first-frame-python-pil

Comment: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4644

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60948028/python-pillow-transparent-gif-isnt-working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, [*the GIF format does not support alpha-channel transparency like PNG does. You can only select one out of the 256 possible colors in a GIF to be transparent*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1952389/11089932). So, you also don't get any smooth transparencies, pixels are either fully transparent or opaque.

When dealing with `Image` objects having [mode](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#modes) `RGBA`, try to convert all your images to mode `PA` before saving. Maybe, that helps *automagically*.

Let's assume we have the following three images:

[image: Red]

[image: Green]

[image: Blue]

Your minimized code would look like this:

```py
from PIL import Image

frames = [Image.open('red.png'), Image.open('green.png'), Image.open('blue.png')]

frames[0].save('test.gif', format='GIF',
               append_images=frames[1:],
               save_all=True,
               duration=200, loop=0, transparency=0)
```

The resulting GIF in fact doesn't reflect the transparency from the single PNGs, the GIF is totally corrupted:

[image: Corrupted output]

Adding the conversion to mode `PA`, the code might look like this:

```py
from PIL import Image

frames = [Image.open('red.png'), Image.open('green.png'), Image.open('blue.png')]

frames = [frame.convert('PA') for frame in frames]

frames[0].save('test.gif', format='GIF',
               append_images=frames[1:],
               save_all=True,
               duration=200, loop=0, transparency=0)
```

And, the result is fine, transparency is maintained:

[image: Proper output]

I don't know, if that route works for arbitrary PNGs, but it's worth testing with your images, isn't it? If that doesn't work, you need to provide some of your input images for further testing.

The final approach could be to replace all transparent pixels in your PNGs with a certain color, let's say solid yellow. When saving the GIF later, you'd need to make sure, that all images' palettes store that solid yellow at the same index, and then finally set `transparency` to that index.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
Pillow:        8.1.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. However there is a lot of noise, but I guess I can't do any better with GIF format (my file is really big)