# Transparency is not working for gifs in pil

Tags: python-imaging-library, gif, alpha

Im trying to make a script that takes and input image and fades it out. So far this is my script

```
imgObject = im.open(imageName)
toAppend = []

for i in range(int(256)):
    imgObject.putalpha(i)
    toAppend.append(imgObject)
    #imgObject.save('images/'+str(i)+'.png', 'PNG')

imgObject.save('finished.gif', save_all=True, append_images=toAppend)
```

When this is run, the output gif is just a still of the input with no changes. But if i save each image as a png, then the transparency works! It saves 255 different images where you can see it fade out. I've also tried stitching these photos together after the fact, but the same or similar problems occurred.
I've also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376359/how-to-create-a-transparent-gif-or-png-with-pil-python-imaging/8377135), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753190/programmatically-generate-video-or-animated-gif-in-python), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44947505/how-to-make-a-movie-out-of-images-in-python), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59729587/animated-gifs-are-only-transparent-on-their-first-frame-python-pil). All producing the same effect.

Comment: You can't have "smooth transparencies" with GIF, pixels can be either fully transparent or opaque, cf. [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66453943/11089932).

Comment: Well my final goal is to have it fade INTO another image, so would it work if the image below it is at full opacity? If so, how would you go about layering 2 images on top of each other?

Answer (score 0):

Read more into the docs and found this

```
imgObject = im.open(imageName)
bpiObject = im.open(backroundName)
toAppend = []

for i in range(100):
    imgObject = im.blend(imgObject, bpiObject, i/100)
    toAppend.append(imgObject)

imgObject.save('finished.gif', save_all=True, append_images=toAppend, loop = 0)
```

This worked for me, they do have to have the same dimensions though